# how to store JSON Parse data in Iphone Locally?

Tags: iphone

I want to store JSON parse data(companyName and companyID) in Iphone locally. I also can add or delete  JSON parse data(companyName and companyID) in store data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the amount of data you wanna store. If it's gonna be less then 1000 I would recommend you to store it as plist, otherwise you can use core data or SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this article will help you out... it's for Flickr but shows how to play with JSON :)

http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: You might want to post the article aswell.

Comment: Or perhaps not as it's in 3 parts.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use NSUserDefaults if it´s just about a single company, not a collection

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

if not SQLite would be the best solution

Comment: Core Data is better than SQLite for most cases in speed and complexity. And while NSUserDefaults is not much different than a plist, conceptually is intended to save user defaults. Using a plist instead is only a couple of lines.